# Count occurence of a value in a column and add to new column in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, count

I have a table like so

```
DBName         RunID          SegNo
FM1            42              1
FM2            47              2
FM2            47              3
```

I would like the number of time the RunID is occured in a new column. The result will be as below

```
DBName         RunID          SegNo         Position
FM1            42              1              1  
FM2            47              2              1
FM2            47              3              2
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT DBName, RunID, SegNo,
       Position = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RunID ORDER BY DBName)
FROM dbo.Table1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd874/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. It partially works, I might be doing something incorrect. I get 6 rows as result first three where the position number is null and next three with correct position numbers.

Comment: SQL:
exec(' INSERT INTO ' + temp_table_distincts + '
  (
  [DBName],
  [RunID],
  [COutputData_3_Segment_Number]
  )
select distinct DBName, RunID, [COutputData_3_Segment_Number] from ' + temp_table_afterpivot_SegRpt_final_distinct + '
order by [COutputData_3_Segment_Number] asc' )

exec(' INSERT INTO ' + temp_table_distincts + '
  (
  [DBName],
  [RunID],
  [COutputData_3_Segment_Number],
  PositionNumber
  )

select DBName, RunID, [COutputData_3_Segment_Number], Position = Row_Number() 
over (Partition by RunID Order by [COutputData_3_Segment_Number] asc) from '  
+ temp_table_distincts)

Comment: Sorry the code is not formatting correctly and temp tables are prefixed with at symbol.

Comment: @Abe: it's difficult to help in comments. However, why don't you update this column instead of insert? Then the `Row_Number` should calculate the correct value.